# Split string by capital letter but ignore AAA Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My regex:

```
vendor = "MyNameIsJoe. I'mWorkerInAAAinc."
ven = re.split(r'(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]|[A-Z](?=[a-z])', vendor)
```

To split strings by capital letter, for example:

**'MyNameIsJoe. I'mWorkerInAAAinc'** becomes '**My Name Is Joe. I'm Worker In AAA inc.'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall()` in order to find the expected words rather than splitting:

```
In [46]: ' '.join(re.findall(r'[A-Z]?[^A-Z\s]+|[A-Z]+', vendor))
Out[46]: "My Name Is Joe. I'm Worker In AAA inc."
```

Note that this opting `[A-Z]+` will match the `AAA` which means any combinations of uppercase letters with length <1 if you don't want this you can simple just use `AAA`.

Comment: Doesn't work if you change `AAA` to `AA` in `vendor`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to split the string on the AAA and then apply your regex on the remaining strings?

Comment: @Harvey I just mentioned that. Regarding splitting from `AAA` I don't think if it's a good way since you have to traverse the string two-three times.

Comment: Re: AA, it doesn't work. It should return `"My Name Is Joe. I'm Worker In A A inc." If we're being pedantic, AAAA doesn't work too.

Comment: I describe that in answer, there might be a lot of other cases too, but it's all depends on how OP want's to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub`:

```
re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])([A-Z]+)', r'\g<3>\g<1> \g<2>', vendor)
```